# sstableloaderによる別keyspaceへのsstableファイル構成の再現

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra 3.0の環境です。

テストの為、あるkeyspaceにあるsstableファイルをそのままに別のkeyspaceに複製して、コンパクションのテストをしたいと思って、います。

sstableloaderならば、実現可能かと思い試してしますが、今一つ上手くいきません。
試した方法は、
・元のkeyspaceでsnapshotを取得する。
・コピー先のkeyspaceにsnapshotの中身のファイルを全てコピーする。
・sstableloader -d localhost <コピー先のkeyspaceのディレクトリパス>
です。

実施後、selectで確認したところテーブル格納データはコピーされていましたが、
sstableloaderを実施したタイミングで、コピー先のsstableのファイル構成が変化しました。
そしてCassandraを再起動したところsstabledumpでsstableを見ようとしたらエラーとなり壊れた様でした。

私のやろうとしている事は可能なのでしょうか。
また、可能な場合、どの様にしたら正しくできるでしょうか。

ご教示頂ければ、幸いです。

Comment: どうやらCassandra自体が起動後、すぐに停止していました。Cassandra自体が壊れてしまった様です。

Answer (score 0):

自己回答です。
単にsstableをコピーして、Cassandraを再起動する事で今のところ問題ない様です。

以前の他の回答でコピー後にnodetool refresh  で上手く行くと
ありましたが、これはコマンド実行時にエラーは出ませんでしたが、selectするとエラーとなりました。

やはり、コピーして再起動で良い様に思います。
もし問題があれば、ご指摘頂けないでしょうか。